# no class def found error when starting activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am getting no class def found error when starting activity from one activity to another. I am using android studio ide. Its simple i don't know why it is giving me this error because it is working fine for another activity.I am using below code..Its very simple i dont know it is suddenly giving me no class def found error.

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.bhu.var" >

<application
    android:name=".application.BHUApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/BHUTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

       <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        </activity>
        </application>
        </manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
 10-31 09:25:21.034  32645-32645/com.bhu.var E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class       
'com.bhu.var.Activity2', referenced from method com.bhu.var.SplashScreen$1.handleMessage
 10-31 09:25:24.260  32645-32645/com.bhu.var E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.bhu.var, PID: 32645
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.bhu.var.Activity2
        at com.pepup.league.launcher.SplashScreen$1.handleMessage(SplashScreen.java:45)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your manifest and logcat!

Comment: Do you have register this activity in manifest file?

Comment: Yeah I already registered it.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild again.

Comment: Tried and also restart android studio but not working.

Comment: Is your activity Activity2 under package com.bhu.var ?

Comment: java returns noclassdef even when one dependency of one import of the class is missing. Maybe u´re using an interface or some kind of factory without the implementation being packaged??

Comment: check that the activity class is in the same package and that the class is defined correctly, ie spelling, extending the correct super class etc